# How to display wget status running in background with `-b` flag ?

Tags: wget

I have several wget processes running in background mode .

they are taking a little longer than I hoped they would

I would like to know % of the download as well as the speed ?

note : file sizes are increasing !

Answer (score 0):

wget creates a file with name of `wget-log0` , `wget-log1` and so on depending on how many downloads have you made .

open the file in a  text editor .

last line is the status of the download .

example

`82200K  ..........  7% 18.1K 17h41m`

this shows .. how many `k` it has downloaded already , `%` of the download and `size` as how much `time` left